# Theme placement.info file not being used

Tags: orchardcms

I am currently trying to reposition a few fields in my theme using the placement.info file in the root of the theme folder.

I have created a new content type called GeneralTemplate.

In my placement.info file, I have

```
<Match ContentType="GeneralTemplate">
    <Place Fields_Common_Text-SubTitle="/Content:1"/>
    <Place Fields_Common_Text-FooterText="/Content:6"/>
</Match>
```

However when I load the page and use the designer tools and view the Placement tab on those fields, it is still using the file at ~/Core/Common/Placement.info.

I have also tried moving the place tags outside of any match tags in case my match tag was incorrect with the same result.

Is there something I am missing as to why the theme placement.info file is not being used?

Comment: Try removing the / in front of the Content:1 and Content:6

Comment: I tried that with the same results

Comment: Enabled your theme? ^_^

Comment: Yeah the theme is enabled. I can get around it by adding the items in the default placement files, but I would prefer to have the theme placement file be picked up

Comment: Does the theme placement.info file has the parent node <Placement>. Is there a Web.config on the theme root?